# SSH isn't supported for your selected stack version

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-web-app-service

SSH isn't supported for your selected stack version.

[image]

application is running and I'm able to access it via web browser, I have deployed java Java-based application.
it is a custom dockized image.
i have attached the screen shot for the reference

Answer (score 0):

Yes,SSH  option in Configuration section is disabled for Java Applications.

I have tried with `Instance details` =>`Publish` with both the options - `Docker Container` and `Code`, In both the applications SSH is disabled.
[image]

- Even in .NET ,Node and Python Docker Container Apps, the option is disabled.
- I can see that the option is available for .NET , Node and Python Applications (with publish - code).

[image]

- For Java Applications, you can check the SSH option under Development Tools.

[image]

[image]

Refer [SSH Access for Container App](https://www.easydeploy.io/blog/enable-ssh-access-for-container-app-hosted-in-azure-app-service/#:%7E:text=Login%20into%20your%20Azure%20Portal%20%E2%80%93%3E%20Navigate%20to,the%20repo%20by%20navigating%20into%20the%20document%20root) for more details.